# Запятая между прилагательными-определениями в неполном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прилагательные, определения

*Выбирай простое разговорное слово вместо сложного(,) официального.*

Тут "сложного" и "официального" не являются однородными, существительное "слова " опущено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Сложное официальное,* как и *простое разговорное* может, на усмотрение автора, писаться как через запятую, так и без, но в Вашем случае всё очень конкретно:

*простое разговорное* противопоставлено *сложному официальному*.

Симметрия такая: либо две запятые, либо нисколько.

А полнота предложения отдыхает.

Comment: Т.е. правильный вариант: "Выбирай простое разговорное слово вместо сложного официального"?

Comment: Да! Это решение автора! Или две запятые,или ни одной!

Answer (score 1):

Эти пары слов сближены по значению, поэтому их **нужно обозначить как однородные**.

Например, так:

**Выбирай слово простое, разговорное вместо сложного и официального.**

Comment: А если определения внутри пар не были бы сближены по значению, могли бы два неоднородных определения употребиться без определяемого слова (оно опущено): "вместо сложного официального"?